# connect to socket.io from Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, vue.js

Say I have two servers (express for serving my Vue SPA [port 8080], and express+ socket as an API [port 8082]).

I want to open socket connection just in case the user is authenticated (authentication made in ajax against the server running on port 8082).

So assume after user logged in, the app redirect to the home page.
I created Home.vue component where I tried (inside the created hook) to import the socket.io script for the client and open connection:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    Home
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import config from '../../../config/env'
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  
  created() {
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script')
    scriptElement.type = "text/javascript"

    scriptElement.src = `http://${config.baseSocketUrl}/socket.io/socket.io.js`
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);

    scriptElement.onload(() => {
      const socket = io(config.crmSocket_nsp)

      socket.on('welcome', (data) => {
        alert(data)
      })
    })
  }
}

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

it didn't go well ^^'

so I was trying to put the script tag hard-coded inside the index.html file where the app mounted () and then use the same method to connect the socket inside the created life cycle hook. Yet didn't go well.
The io here is undefined!

Any direction will be blessed!
thanks all!

Comment: are you using webpack or something to build your vue app? you might need to require io there or add it to the window

Answer (score 0):

It should works at the stage `beforeMount()` instead of `created()`